# translating a C while loop to Pascal

Tags: c, pascal

I am translating a C program and have the following loop:

```
while (octaves--) {
  /* do stuff */
}
```

should this be:

```
while (octaves > 0) do
  begin
    // do stuff
    dec(octaves);
  end;
```

or should be decrement be *before* the loop content?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: It should be before

Comment: This is very easy to write a small test program to investigate how this works. Try both the c and the pascal version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of the c code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int i = 3;
  while(i--){
      printf("%x,\n",i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

this prints

```
2,
1,
0,
```

The same program can be written as

```
int main(){
  int i = 3;
  while(i){
      i--;
      printf("%x,\n",i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Which produces the same output. This code can now be directly translated to pascal.

```
while (i > 0) do
  begin
    dec(i);
    // do stuff
    writeln(i);
  end;
```

Comment: I have not written pascal since 1993 if I made some syntax error ;-) above

Comment: Thanks Simson; much appreciated. BTW, the "println" would be "writeln". :)

Comment: @StevePeter you should try to make this kind of research before you post a question here, there will be other problems from your c program which which a small test program would reveal for you and if it doesn't it will be a better question.

Comment: @StevePeter I also think for your project you should set up a debugger for both the c and pascal version so you can single step both and verify they are equal.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions, Simson. At present I don't have a C compiler on my computer; I guess I should work out whether GCC is still around. :)

Comment: @StevePeter For just trying out a snippet you could try this: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler